Auto Delete Soldout Items (Shopify)
I'm building shopify app using Express and React.
I made api to delete soldout items (quantity = 0)
This is shopify.js file.
import { BillingInterval, LATEST_API_VERSION } from '@shopify/shopify-api';
import { shopifyApp } from '@shopify/shopify-app-express';
import { MongoDBSessionStorage } from '@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage-mongodb';
import { restResources } from '@shopify/shopify-api/rest/admin/2024-04';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const shopify = shopifyApp({
  api: {
    apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
    restResources,
    billing: undefined
  },
  auth: {
    path: '/api/auth',
    callbackPath: '/api/auth/callback'
  },
  webhooks: {
    path: '/api/webhooks'
  },
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  sessionStorage: new MongoDBSessionStorage(
    process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    process.env.DATABASE_NAME
  )
});

export default shopify;

initial file index.js.
// @ts-check
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import express from 'express';
import serveStatic from 'serve-static';

import shopify from './shopify.js';
import productCreator from './product-creator.js';
import PrivacyWebhookHandlers from './privacy.js';
import deleteSoldOutItems from './deleteSoldOutItems.js';

const PORT = parseInt(
  process.env.BACKEND_PORT || process.env.PORT || '3000',
  10
);

const STATIC_PATH =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? `${process.cwd()}/frontend/dist`
    : `${process.cwd()}/frontend/`;

const app = express();

// Set up Shopify authentication and webhook handling
app.get(shopify.config.auth.path, shopify.auth.begin());
app.get(
  shopify.config.auth.callbackPath,
  shopify.auth.callback(),
  shopify.redirectToShopifyOrAppRoot()
);
app.post(
  shopify.config.webhooks.path,
  shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: PrivacyWebhookHandlers })
);

// If you are adding routes outside of the /api path, remember to
// also add a proxy rule for them in web/frontend/vite.config.js

app.use('/api/*', shopify.validateAuthenticatedSession());

app.use(express.json());


app.delete('/api/products/delete-sold-out', async (_req, res) => {
  let status = 200;
  let error = null;

  try {
    await deleteSoldOutItems(res.locals.shopify.session);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Failed to delete sold-out products: ${e.message}`);
    status = 500;
    error = e.message;
  }
  res.status(status).send({ success: status === 200, error });
});

app.use(shopify.cspHeaders());
app.use(serveStatic(STATIC_PATH, { index: false }));

app.use('/*', shopify.ensureInstalledOnShop(), async (_req, res, _next) => {
  return res
    .status(200)
    .set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    .send(readFileSync(join(STATIC_PATH, 'index.html')));
});

app.listen(PORT);

This is my index.jsx frontend page.
import { TitleBar } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
import { Layout, Page, Button } from '@shopify/polaris';
import { useAuthenticatedFetch } from '../hooks/index.js';

export default function HomePage() {
  const fetch = useAuthenticatedFetch();

  const handleArchive = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('/api/products/delete-sold-out', {
        method: 'DELETE'
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to archive sold out items:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Page narrowWidth>
      <TitleBar title='Auto archive sold out items' primaryAction={null} />
      <Layout>
        <Layout.Section>
          <Button primary onClick={handleArchive}>
            Archive sold out items
          </Button>
        </Layout.Section>
      </Layout>
    </Page>
  );
}

I deployed it on Heroku.
When I installed the app everything worked fine.
What I need is to implement this functionality automatically.
I know I can use the Heroku scheduler for that, but I do not know how to implement it with Shopify apps.
Shopify version is (2024-04).
